# How do I dynamically assign a function to a control's onClick property

Tags: ms-access, events, vba

On a control in an access form, I'd like to dynamically change what function is called with the `onClick` property.

So, there is a function, say

```
public function m(a as string)
    call msgBox(a)
end function
```

And somewhere, in another piece of code, I have this

```
dim nb as navigationButton
set nb = createNavigationButton(.....)
nb.name = "nav...."
nb.onClick = "=m(""dummy"")"
```

*I had this working*

But then, I changed something, but I do not know what it is. Now, when the line `nb.onClick` is called, access tells me the rather unhelpful **Run-time-error '7960': There was an error compiling the function**

Note, I can't use an "ordinary" eventhandler (`sub navXYZ_Click`) because the control is created dynamically.

Comment: What is your "createNavigationButton()" function? are you returning a proper "NavigationButton" to nb?

Comment: @krish I think it would throw an error on the 2nd line if that wasn't the case. Assuming your function "m" isn't just a msgbox, could you post that function as well?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like this:

```
Command0.OnClick = "=m(""dummy"")"
Command0.Caption = "Hello"
```

This is tested and working in Access 2010

I tested this with function m(a as string) in both it's own module and in the module behind the form and it worked perfectly both ways.